# LateX: circuitikz & table side by side with minipage

Tags: floats, tikz-pgf

I'm having a hard time with minipage: I'd like to put a table side by side with a circuit (drawn with circuitikz), I looked up and did as suggested in other posts (putting `%` after `\end{minipage}`, using `[ht]` instead of `[h]`, adjusting the width of the minipage, etc.), but it still doesn't work, what am I getting wrong? Thanks in advance!

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%I included all the packages I used, if it matters 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
```

```latex
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{center} 
{\tiny \begin{tabular}{ccc||ccc} \hline 
$f_{j} [Hz]$ & $V_{in_{j}} \pm 0.06$ [V] & $V_{out_{j}}$ [V] & $f_{j}$ [Hz] & $V_{in_{j}} \pm 0.06$ [V] & $V_{out_{j}}$ [V] \\
\hline
\hline
-&-&-&-&-&-\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}}
\caption{blabla}  \label{T:data}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}%
\end{table}%
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{center}
{\tiny \begin{circuitikz} [scale=.8, transform shape]
      \draw (0,0)
      to[sV] (0, 1.4)     
      to[R=$R$] (1.4,1.4)
      to[C=$C$] (1.4,0)
      to(1.4,0)node[ground]{}
      to[short](0,0);
      \draw(1.4,1.4)
      to[short, -o] (1.4, 1.8) {} node[above = .5mm] {$V_{out}$};
      \draw (0,1.4)
      to[short, -o] (0,1.8) {} node[above =.5mm]{$V_{in}$};
    \end{circuitikz}}
\caption{bla}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi! I believe that `tabular`, `center`, `minipage` and `table` nested are far too much stuff to work _as expected_...

Comment: Also, why `tiny`, when you can `scale` your `circuitikz`?

Answer (score 1):

As I commented above, one would like to keep it all as simple as possible: for this reason I opted for nesting only one `tabular` into one `center` environment (that you can switch back to `figure` if you are *sure* you want a float). Then I put each of your two contents (`tabular` and `circuitikz`) in a cell of the former `tabular`.

The code that follows can be pretty much refined (particularly regarding captions). I only added package `array`, allowing me to center the contents in the two columns using the syntax in lines marked as `% 1`, `% 2`, `% 3`.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%I included all the packages I used, if it matters
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array} % 1

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}} % 2

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{C{.7\textwidth}C{.3\textwidth}} % 3
%
        {\tiny
            \begin{tabular}{ccc||ccc}
                \hline
                $f_{j} [Hz]$ & $V_{in_{j}} \pm 0.06$ [V] & $V_{out_{j}}$ [V] & $f_{j}$ [Hz] & $V_{in_{j}} \pm 0.06$ [V] & $V_{out_{j}}$ [V] \\
                \hline
                \hline
                -&-&-&-&-&-\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        }\par%\par\phantom{ }\par
    blabla
%
    &
%
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=.8, transform shape]
        \draw (0,0)
            to[sV] (0, 1.4)
            to[R=$R$] (1.4,1.4)
            to[C=$C$] (1.4,0)
            to(1.4,0)node[ground]{}
            to[short](0,0);
        \draw(1.4,1.4)
            to[short, -o] (1.4, 1.8) {} node[above = .5mm] {$V_{out}$};
        \draw (0,1.4)
            to[short, -o] (0,1.8) {} node[above =.5mm]{$V_{in}$};
    \end{circuitikz}\par
    bla
%
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It seems that OP doesn't follow TeX.SX ... Anyway some suggestion regarding tabular environments: **(i)** for outer `tabular` use `\begin{tabular}{C{.75\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} C{.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}`, for this you need to add package `calc` in preamble; **(ii)** before inner `tabular` put `\setcellgapes{7pt}\makegapedcells`, for this you need to add package `makecell` in preamble, and as you already noted, don't use `\tiny`. With this changes the result will become more nice (at least to my taste).